# Python DataFrame How to split or extract date from a datetime stamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I want to extract the date from a datetime stamp to write in Print function for title purpose of figure. Following is my code:

```
plt.title('%s day IV curves of sample Module'%(module_allData_df['Time'].loc[i].replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)))
```

output is:

[image]

But I want the title to be as:

```
2016-08-13 day IV curves of sample Module
```

I don't want the time stamp to appear there. How to do it?

I have modified the code as per following accepted answer of `@jezrael` and it worked. Here is the code and solution:

```
plt.title('%s day IV curves of sample Module'%(module_allData_df['Time'].loc[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

Output is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html):

```
val = module_allData_df['Time'].loc[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

plt.title('{} day IV curves of sample Module'.format(val))
```

And for python 3.6+:

```
plt.title(f'{val} day IV curves of sample Module')
```